# Mono FastCGI in Lighttpd extends my ASP.NET Response

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono, debian, lighttpd

I am using mono (3.0.6) for the first time on a Debian machine, in combination with lighttpd.

My test site contains one ASPX file with the following code:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
Response.Write("Hello Mono!");
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

This is the Response (HTTP text) from an IIS 8.0 server:

```
Hello Mono!
```

And this is the response from the mono server:

```
59
Hello Mono!
<empty line>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating Mono to a newer version (3.2.4, compiled from source) solved the problem.

ASP.NET on Mono seems still far from perfect (especially when porting code, written for newer Framework versions), but there have been noticeable improvements in the last months.